# height:100% css is not working

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I have set up a jfiddle example, and it seems like my height:100%; is not working.

```
body, html 
{
    height:100%;    
}

#full-wrap {
    min-height:100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 0 -91px;    /* 1 extra px from footer border */
    clear:both;
    border:thin solid red;
}
.contentCenter {
    min-height:100%;
    height:100%;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    clear:both;
    border:thin solid blue;

}


.footer {
    height:90px;width:100%;
    border-top:1px #E8E8E8 solid;
    clear:both;
}    


<div id='full-wrap'>
    <div class='contentCenter'>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='footer'>
</div>
```

Can someone help me with the problem? as you can see that the border line (blue) is not going 100%.

Comment: your code is right #full-wrap take 100% height but not his child

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
height: auto !important;
```

Remove that line and it works.

Comment: thanks! quick questions. if you can help me. I have another div, with float:left. I set a float left because I needed to be next to another div, but I was wondering if its possible to set height:100% with a float left? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The height of your parent `#full-wrap` div is set to `height:auto`, you need to specify a height in order for your child div to expand 100%, so set it to 100% or a fixed height. Remember, percentage-based height is relative to its container.